# Access2013: Record Set not Updatable

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form which adds/edits records of a table [Unit Owner Listing].  Additionally, I have brought in a sharepoint list [Sales and Contract Summary] and created a relationship to the table [Unit Owner Listing] which is in Access.  Essentially, new data is added to the [Unit Owner Listing] and whatever comes from the sharepoint [Sales and Contract Summary] is locked on the form (to create a read-only effect).  I only want to see the data from the SharePoint if there is data available to join in, and I do not want to write any data to the sharepoint, only to the table [Unit Owner Listing] for the fields which are available

I believe this is where the problem has come up... now, I cannot add any new records to the form, the button is greyed out.  How do I accomplish this?

**To Save Time:** "Allow Additions, Deletions, Edits and Filters" are all set to yes on the form properties.

**The Form Query is below:**

```
SELECT [Unit Owner Listing].*, [Sales and Contract Summary].Status, [Sales and Contract Summary].[Assigned To], [Sales and Contract Summary].[Total Sale], [Sales and Contract Summary].Sqft, [Sales and Contract Summary].[Foam Encaps], [Sales and Contract Summary].[Notes/Action Plan], [Sales and Contract Summary].[Closed Date], [Sales and Contract Summary].Modified
FROM [Sales and Contract Summary] INNER JOIN [Unit Owner Listing] ON [Sales and Contract Summary].[Lot Number] = [Unit Owner Listing].Address;
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has supposedly fixed my problem.  I believe mixing the data sets was causing the issue and this setting allows access to update more than 1 dataset at a time with the form (for example, access + sharepoint interaction).  Hope this helps someone else.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/recordsettype-property-HA001232788.aspx